# Adding a new language support in base languages supported by Sphinx

Tags: internationalization, python-sphinx

I refer to the Internationalization documentation of Sphinx at http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/advanced/intl.html

The base documentation need to be created in one of the supported languages at http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-language.

Now we can generate PO files for another language and proceed with translation work. The generation of base documentation and translation process is well document in sphinx documentation.

My question is how do I add language support for a new language in the base languages supported by Sphinx?

I'm specifically looking to create the base document in Hindi (hi) and then follow the translation process with sphinx-intl in English (en) and other languages. I see the support of 38 languages in currently supported languages by Sphinx.

Maybe some expert who extended the support to one of those languages can provide some guidance to add support of a new language to the base languages. If I'm missing any existing documentation on above topic, any pointer to the documentation is appreciated.

Comment: I found Dev Guide (http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/devguide.html) which includes process of locale updates (http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/devguide.html#locale-updates). The translations are maintained at Transifex. I've submitted the hi locale translation at https://www.transifex.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx-1/language/hi/. It should get shipped with v2.0.0 package. The same process will be applicable for any new locale.